# Jquery slidershow on cross browser implementation fail

Tags: jquery, slideshow

Here's my code for an image slider carousel that's set to 100% width of a page. My question is why does this work correctly on everything but versions of IE? 
IE 8=Carousel is at the end.
IE 7/6 = All the images are stacked.

See it:
http://henryquindara.com/_this/

**JS:**

```
var imageContainer = $('#imageContainer .container');
var imgs = $('#imageContainer .container .imageThumb');
var imgsDisp = $('#imageContainer .container .imageThumb img');
var imgsWidth;
var navWidth = 0;
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var cnt = 0;
var imgOffset;
var navOffset;
var curImg = 1;

$(window).resize(function() 
{
    windowWidth = $(window).width();
    imgOffset =  (imgsWidth - windowWidth) / windowWidth;
    navOffset = (navWidth - windowWidth) / windowWidth;
    $('#imageContainer').css('width',windowWidth);
});

imageContainer.find('img').each(function()
{
    var $img    = $(this);
    $img.load(function()
    {
        ++cnt;
        if(cnt == imgs.length)
        {
            imgWidth = imageContainer.find('.imageThumb:first').width();
            imgHeight = imageContainer.find('.imageThumb:first').height();
            imgsWidth = (imgWidth * imgs.length) + (5 * imgs.length);
            imgOffset =  (imgsWidth - windowWidth) / windowWidth;
            $('#imageContainer').css({width:windowWidth});
            $('#imageContainer .container').css({width:imgsWidth});
            centerCurImg();
        }
        sizeImg($img, imageContainer.find('.imageThumb:first').width()-0, imageContainer.find('.imageThumb:first').height()-0);
        $img.css({'opacity':'.4'});
    })
});

$('#prev-btn').click(prevClickAdj);
$('#next-btn').click(nextClickAdj);

function centerCurImg()
{
    var destX = (windowWidth / 2 ) - (imgWidth*(curImg+1)) + (imgWidth/2);
    imageContainer.stop().animate({left:destX}, 400, 'easeOutCirc', function(){
        sizeHot();
    });
}

function sizeHot()
{
    $(imgsDisp[curImg]).stop().animate({height:imgHeight, width:imgWidth, opacity:1}, 400, 'easeOutCirc');

}

function sizeImg ( target, val, val2 )
{
    $(target).css({'width' : val, 'height' : val2});
}

function prevClickAdj()
{
    $(imgsDisp[curImg]).stop().animate({height:imgHeight-0, width:imgWidth-0, opacity:.4}, 400, 'easeOutCirc', function()
            {
        centerCurImg(); 
    });

    curImg --;
    checkArrows();

}

function nextClickAdj()
{
    //$(imgsDisp[curImg]).stop().animate({height:imgHeight-0, width:imgWidth-0, opacity:.4}, 400, 'easeOutCirc', function()
            {
        centerCurImg(); 
    });

    curImg ++;
    checkArrows();  
}

function checkArrows()
{
    if ( curImg > 0 )  $('#prev-btn').show();
    else $('#prev-btn').hide(); 

    if ( curImg < imgs.length-1 )  $('#next-btn').show();
    else $('#next-btn').hide(); 
}
```

**HTML**

```
            <div id="imageContainer">

                <div class="container">

                    <div class="imageThumb"> 

                        <div class="imageFull"><img src="/images/newyork/img_1.jpg" /></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="imageThumb"> 

                        <div class="imageFull"><img src="/images/newyork/img_2.jpg" /></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="imageThumb"> 

                        <div class="imageFull"><img src="/images/newyork/img_3.jpg" /></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="imageThumb"> 

                        <div class="imageFull"><img src="/images/newyork/img_1.jpg" /></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="imageThumb"> 

                        <div class="imageFull"><img src="/images/newyork/img_2.jpg" /></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="imageThumb"> 

                        <div class="imageFull"><img src="/images/newyork/img_3.jpg" /></div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>



        <div id="prev-btn"><a href="#">Previous</a></div>

        <div id="next-btn"><a href="#">Next</a></div>

    </div>
```

ANY HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED!

Comment: Html code would be useful to see or even better a working page that can be inspected.

Comment: Can you link to a live version, or http://jsfiddle.net it?

Comment: Here you go [http://henryquindara.com/_this/]